# flow in model-glue event handler

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, model-glue

Can any body help me to understand the flow of model-glue event handler......its so confusing  or simplify bellow code......

```
  <event-handler name="Shipment.List" type="templatedPage">
        <broadcasts>
            <message name="needShipmentList" />
        </broadcasts>
        <views>
            <include name="Primary" template="List.Shipment.cfm">
                <value name="xe_Display" value="Shipment.Display" />
                <value name="xe_Form" value="Shipment.Form" />
            </include>
        </views>
    </event-handler>

    <event-handler name="Shipment.Display" type="templatedPage">
        <broadcasts>
            <message name="needShipmentDetail" />
        </broadcasts>
        <views>
            <include name="primary" template="Display.Shipment.cfm">
                <value name="xe_ShipmentList" value="Shipment.List" />
                <value name="xe_ItemForm" value="Item.Form" />
                <value name="xe_ShipmentDisplay" value="Shipment.Display" />
                <value name="xe_ItemRemove" value="doItem.Remove" />
            </include>
        </views>
    </event-handler>
```

Comment: I don't know MG, but that snippet looks relatively straightforward. Have you read [the documentation](https://github.com/modelglue/modelglue-framework/wiki)? What _specifically_ are you confused about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call for event "Shipment.List", it will broadcasts `"needShipmentList"` function of ShipmentController, after execution it will return on `List.Shipment.cfm` from on "Primary" layout of master page.

- "List.Shipment.cfm" has a link whicj is triggered for `needShipmentDetail` function
- "List.Shipment.cfm" fatches values from `"Shipment.Display"-->needShipmentDetail`
- on display page(`Display.Shipment.cfm`), there are some links for remove, for listing...etc
- `"xe"` is a convention for eXit Events